# Bitrix CMS, Apach 2.4 (VertrigoServ) htaccess issue

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, bitrix

I've been struggling whole day with that issue, but still have no clue, why it does not work. I deployed a website from hosting to local server to test/update purposes. Admin park works fine, main page works fine and directories and components work fine. But every component which relies on url -rewrite engine fails to work. It sends me to 404. For example I can look through /catalog/ directory but if I request /commodity/good/ I am sent to 404, so happens with news component etc. I've tried many variations of server config but result either the same either server error.

I reset my experiments to default config, it seems it has to work

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\VertrigoServ\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And it seems it works, but in a strange manner. If I add Redirect instruction to .htaccess it performs that redirect. But Bitrix does not work properly anyway.

Here is what I left in main .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

If you faced similar issue please help me to find solution...

Comment: I found a solution. To whoever uses VertrigoServ, please take into account that it has module mod_rewrite being turned off by default.